# One figure having two columns of subfigures: the left column has one image and the right one has two images

Tags: subfloats

I am trying to create a subfigure in LaTeX similar to this image:

[image]

I want to have a figure which has two columns. The left column contains one image and the right columns has two images. In fact, the right column is divided into two rows and the sum of the heights of the two images in the right column is equal to the height of the image in the left column. Is there a way to create such a figure in LaTeX?

I have been trying to adjust different versions of the following code but no success.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure
        []
        {\label{fig:figA}}
        \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{figA}
    \hspace{0.005\textwidth}    
    \subfigure
        []
        {\label{fig:figB}}
        \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{figB}
    \hspace{0.005\textwidth}    
    \subfigure
        []
        {\label{fig:figC}}
        \includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{figC}                
    \caption{my caption. (a) is .... (b) is .... (c) is ....}
    \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks,
Ahmad

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I uploaded your image using the official interface (i.e., by clicking the button above the text field). This is preferred, as it reduces the chance of dead image links.

Comment: Also, are you using the [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package? That is actually deprecated, `subfig` or `subcaption` is recommended instead.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you need a reputation of at least 10 to upload images, and the OP did not have that when he asked the question :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. actually, you were precise. I didn't know he could upload the images... I am going to delete my comments after giving you time to see this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use some `minipage` environment and `\sbox` to measure the height of the biggest box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\measurebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\sbox{\measurebox}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\textwidth}
  \subfloat
    []
    {\label{fig:figA}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{figA}}
  \end{minipage}}
\usebox{\measurebox}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht\measurebox][s]{.33\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat
  []
  {\label{fig:figB}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{figB}}

\vfill

\subfloat
  []
  {\label{fig:figC}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{figC}}
\end{minipage}
\caption{my caption. (a) is .... (b) is .... (c) is ....}
\label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I've used `subfig` and not the obsolete `subfigure`. Also `subcaption` can be a choice and should if you use `hyperref`.

The `demo` option to `graphicx` is just to produce some mock pictures; I gave them a height to show the example.

[image]