# Figure with two columns, one subfigure on the first column, two on the second column

Tags: floats, subfloats

How can I have a figure (with a caption) that has three subfigures (each with its own caption, say (a), (b) and (c)) with the following layout: There are two columns; the first column is a single subfigure, the second column consists of two subfigures stacked vertically:

[image]

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87975/116986

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `subcaption` and `minipage`s you can achieve this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}% >>>
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \subcaptionbox{text1}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \subcaptionbox{text2}
      {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
    \subcaptionbox{text3}
      {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \caption
    {%
      Caption.%
      \label{fig:caption}%
    }%
\end{figure}% <<<

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `subfig` package as though one has tried to read its manual:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}% >>>
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \subfloat[text1]
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \subfloat[text2]
      {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}\\
    \subfloat[text3]
      {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \caption
    {%
      Caption.%
      \label{fig:caption}%
    }%
\end{figure}% <<<

\end{document}
```

Output is almost identical.

Comment: Thanks! it works. However, I was using the subfig package for some other figures and it is incompatible with subcaption. Is there a similar solution with subfig instead of subcaption?

Comment: @AbolfazlKarimi yes. You know that you can read its manual?

Comment: @AbolfazlKarimi See new answer below (it uses `subcaption` instead)

Answer (score 0):

With the more modern `subcaption` package, you can simply nest `subfigure` for advanced layouts, like so:

## Result

[image]

## Code

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[th]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.65\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test}
      \caption{1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill  % NOTE1: hfill moves horizontally stacked objects as far apart as it can
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
      \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test}
        \caption{2}
      \end{subfigure}
      % NOTE2: two empty lines = 1 linebreak


      \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test}
        \caption{3}
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{figure caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## A few things to note

1. You can force linebreaks (i.e. move to the next "row") through several means. The simplest approach is add two empty lines. Conversely, you want to be careful not to insert random empty lines into your figure environment. (E.g. the other day, I wasted an hour debugging this exact problem because I forgot that empty lines insert rows).
2. `\hfill` can be used to space things out horizontally.
3. If the total width of all horizontally stacked subfigure exceeds `\textwidth`, it will also automatically move things to the next line. If you want to use more than `\textwidth`, you have to solve a more complicated problem (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth)).