# Two pictures next to a big one, to fit in textwidth

Tags: graphics, floats, width, height, textwidth

I want two pictures next to another big one and every picture has a different size (like the example below).

[image]

I want that all pictures keep their aspect ratio and the pictures to the right should have the same height. Also all 3 pictures should be as wide as the `\textwidth`.

I've tried `subfigure` and `\resizebox`, but I could not set the right heights dependent on the height of the left picture.
Manually trying to fit all the sizes is way too tedious, is there an easy way to do that?

Edit: 
Here are more informations for my problem. My current code looks like this.
I've just adjustet the sizes of the pictures until they fit (trial end error). A very tedious process.

The pictures have individual caption with (a), (b) and (c) and the whole picture has another caption.

It would be nice to manage the size of the right pictures so that they are not bigger than the left one and that alle 3 pictures don't exceed the linewitdh.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[p]{.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{MMC.eps}
    \caption{MMC Schaltbild, \cite{Eremia.2016}} \label{fig:ch2_MMC
\end{subfigure}
\qquad
\begin{subfigure}[p]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.39\textheight]{Halfbridge.eps}
    \caption{Halfbridge, \cite{Shah.17.07.201621.07.2016}} \label{fig:ch2_Halfbridge}

    \vspace{2ex}

    \includegraphics[height=0.39\textheight]{Fullbridge.eps}
    \caption{Fullbridge, \cite{Shah.17.07.201621.07.2016}} \label{fig:ch2_Fullfbridge}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{MMC and Submodule}\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It is not fun to write code from scratch again, which you already write to to produce the showed image. Please, be so kind and share it to as. Please help us to help you.

Comment: Are the captions individual captions (figure 1, figure 2...) or subcaptions (figure1a, figure 1b...)?

Comment: This question needs more work; please add code that attempts to answer the question, and a clearer notion of the result you want.

Comment: this meets your requirement-------https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302138/197451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we denote by

- *a* and *b* the width and height of the picture on the left,
- *c* and *d* the width and height of the picture on the top right,
- *e* and *f* the width and height of the picture on the bottom right,
- *v* the the gap between the picture on the right,
- *w* the desired total width (a tad less than `\textwidth`),

we can denote by *x*, *y* and *z* the required scale factors for the three pictures (left, top right and bottom right). Then solving the linear system yields

*x* = (2​*fw* + *ev*)/(*be* + 2​*af*)
*y* = (*bfw* - *afv*)/(*bde* + 2​*adf*)
*z* = (*bw* - *av*)/(*be* + 2​*af*)

The obvious limitation is that the second and third scaling factors are positive.

Here's an implementation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xfp}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\sbox0{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\sbox2{\includegraphics{example-image-1x1}}
\sbox4{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}

\edef\Da{\fpeval{\wd0}}\edef\Db{\fpeval{\ht0}}
\edef\Dc{\fpeval{\wd2}}\edef\Dd{\fpeval{\ht2}}
\edef\De{\fpeval{\wd4}}\edef\Df{\fpeval{\ht4}}

\edef\Dv{\fpeval{8ex}}
\edef\Dw{\fpeval{\textwidth-3em}}

\edef\Dx{\fpeval{(2*\Df*\Dw + \De*\Dv)/(\Db*\De + 2*\Da*\Df)}}
\edef\Dy{\fpeval{(\Db*\Df*\Dw - \Da*\Df*\Dv)/(\Db*\Dd*\De + 2*\Da*\Dd*\Df)}}
\edef\Dz{\fpeval{(\Db*\Dw - \Da*\Dv)/(\Db*\De + 2*\Da*\Df)}}

\sbox{0}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\fpeval{\Da*\Dx}pt}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \scalebox{\Dx}{\box0}
  \caption{First pic}
  \end{minipage}%
}\usebox{0}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht0][s]{\fpeval{\Dw-\Da*\Dx}pt}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\scalebox{\Dy}{\box2}
\caption{Second pic}

\vfill

\scalebox{\Dz}{\box4}
\caption{Third pic}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want subfigures, substitute `minipage` with `subfigure`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xfp,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\sbox0{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\sbox2{\includegraphics{example-image-1x1}}
\sbox4{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}

\edef\Da{\fpeval{\wd0}}\edef\Db{\fpeval{\ht0}}
\edef\Dc{\fpeval{\wd2}}\edef\Dd{\fpeval{\ht2}}
\edef\De{\fpeval{\wd4}}\edef\Df{\fpeval{\ht4}}

\edef\Dv{\fpeval{8ex}}
\edef\Dw{\fpeval{\textwidth-3em}}

\edef\Dx{\fpeval{(2*\Df*\Dw + \De*\Dv)/(\Db*\De + 2*\Da*\Df)}}
\edef\Dy{\fpeval{(\Db*\Df*\Dw - \Da*\Df*\Dv)/(\Db*\Dd*\De + 2*\Da*\Dd*\Df)}}
\edef\Dz{\fpeval{(\Db*\Dw - \Da*\Dv)/(\Db*\De + 2*\Da*\Df)}}

\sbox{0}{%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\fpeval{\Da*\Dx}pt}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \scalebox{\Dx}{\box0}
  \caption{First pic}
  \end{subfigure}%
}\usebox{0}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b][\ht0][s]{\fpeval{\Dw-\Da*\Dx}pt}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\scalebox{\Dy}{\box2}
\caption{Second pic}

\vfill

\scalebox{\Dz}{\box4}
\caption{Third pic}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Global caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, very impressive solution. It works very well thanks.
I've got just one question. Is it possible to treat the pictures as subpictures so that they get the same caption number followed by the according letter (a), (b) and (c)?

Comment: @Daniel Added the trick.

Answer (score 1):

an @egreg solution--https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87976/197451

You can use some minipage environment and `\sbox` to measure the height of the biggest box.

Notice that I've used `subfig` and not the obsolete `subfigure`. Also `subcaption` can be a choice and should if you use `hyperref`.

The `demo` option to `graphicx` is just to produce some mock pictures; I gave them a height to show the example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\measurebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\sbox{\measurebox}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\textwidth}
  \subfloat
    []
    {\label{fig:figA}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{figA}}
  \end{minipage}}
\usebox{\measurebox}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht\measurebox][s]{.33\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat
  []
  {\label{fig:figB}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{figB}}

\vfill

\subfloat
  []
  {\label{fig:figC}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{figC}}
\end{minipage}
\caption{my caption. (a) is .... (b) is .... (c) is ....}
\label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```